# How to link top and side navigation in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have following navigation structure, which i want to implement in wordpress:

[image: Navigation Image]

(Home / About / news / Contact) are in top navigation, whereas all sub links are in sidebar.

How can i create this type of navigation in wordpress. i.e. How can i display first level navigation in header and second level navigation in sidebar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. First create a main Navigation to your site without child pages and
   add it to the theme.
2. Then create a new menu with child menus only and save it.
3. Now goto widgets section and from there drag `Custom Menu` from left
   side and add to your sidebar.
4. Then select your child menu and click save.

Thats all. :)

[**Check this WordPress Codex section for creating menu tutorial**](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide)

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i think my question is not clear enough. I want to know how can i display first level navigation in header and second level navigation in sidebar.

Comment: Thanks Libin, how can i add different menus for different pages. Or use different sidebars for different pages? I think i will need to provide some option to client so that he can select which sidebar or menu should be implemented on each page, please suggest?

Comment: Yeah. You can create "page template" for each page and can add separate sidebars for each page template. But if you are looking to list sub-pages of current parent page, then you can do it by coding. [Check this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-current-parent-and-its-sub-menu-only-on-sidebar?replies=6)

Answer (score 1):

I found these plugins helpful:

**Simple Section Navigation**
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-section-navigation/

It allowed me to create the side nav based on the hierarchy of the pages and their children.

I wanted a bit more control though because I didn't want some of the parents to have their own page ... just a heading for their children. So instead, I'm using this plugin (for the Genesis Framework).

**Genesis Simple Sidebars**
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/genesis-simple-sidebars/

This allows me to create as many sidebars as I want and add custom menus to those. I'm new to this, so maybe I'm taking a long route, but so far it seems to be doing what I want it to.